# How would I make a column of numbers in excel using Start number and End number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For Example, If A2 was 5 and B2 was 30 Could I make a column of numbers in the C column starting with 5 and ending 30. Like C1=5, C2=6,C3=7 and so on, until is reaches 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In C1 put `=$A$2`

In C2 put `=IF(C1 < $B$2, C1 + 1, "")`

Then copy the content of C2 to C3, C4, C5, etc. to as many cells as needed. The "counting" will stop when reaching the value in B2.

Answer (score 1):

In ExcelO365, you could use:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SEQUENCE(B2-A2+1,,A2)
```